# SQL nested queries

Tags: sql

Can someone help me to get the following queries strung together on this table..

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TblNdx](
[ticker] [nvarchar](12) NOT NULL,
[date] [datetime] NULL,
[time] [datetime] NULL,
[open] [float] NULL,
[high] [float] NULL,
[low] [float] NULL,
[close] [float] NULL,
[volume] [float] NULL,
[change] [float] NULL
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I need a query that gets the last xxx records WHERE ...

```
SELECT ticker, date, time, [open], high, low, [close], volume, change
FROM   TblNdx 
WHERE  1=1
AND (ticker = '^IXIC') 
AND (date =
        (
            SELECT TOP (1) date as date1
            FROM TblNdx AS TblNdx_1
            WHERE (ticker = '^IXIC')
            ORDER BY date DESC
        )
    )
ORDER BY time DESC
```

AND Then ADD ANOTHER COLUMN TO COMPUTER LASTCLOSE WHICH IS THE PREVIOUS CLOSE FOR THE PRECEDING DAY... DATEDIFF(Day, date, date1) = 1 AND Time is TOP 1 TIME FROM 2nd PREVIOUS DAY... in other words the closing price from the previous day... the nested SELECT TOP 1 Clauses are killing me... anyone good at this?

I did not mean disrespect.  I am a geek that drinks margaritas just like everyone... !  Anyway, I appreciate edits.  To get the the previous last close date  I am trying to modify.. any help with this code it says 'only one expression can be specified in SELECT list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS..

I use Visual Studio to run queries and it indents very strange ways...and I guess I don't really know how to indent properly!!

```
SELECT ticker
    , date
    , time
    , [open]
    , high
    , low
    , [close]
    , volume
    , change
    , (SELECT TOP (1) time AS time1, [close] AS lastclose
         FROM TblNdx WHERE (DATEDIFF(day, date, date1) = 1) 
         AND (ticker = '^IXIC') ORDER BY time1 DESC) AS Expr1
    FROM TblNdx AS TblNdx_2
    WHERE (1 = 1) AND (ticker = '^IXIC') 
    AND (date = (SELECT TOP (1) date AS date1
                    FROM TblNdx AS TblNdx_1 
                    WHERE (ticker = '^IXIC')
                    ORDER BY date1 DESC))
    ORDER BY time DESC
```

Comment: We would all rather go get some margaritas. -1 for not showing any respect.

Comment: I have a feeling you would benefit greatly from indenting your code properly.

Comment: Yelling in SQL is on the corner, but yelling in text is over the corner.

Comment: geez you all are touchy tonight.

Comment: I used this query...
 
    SELECT ticker
  , date
  , time
  , [open]
  , high
  , low
  , [close]
  , volume
  , change
  , (SELECT TOP (1) [close] FROM TblNdx AS t2
    WHERE (DATEDIFF(day, date, t1.date) 
                                 = 2) AND (ticker = t1.ticker)
    ORDER BY time DESC) AS LastClose
  FROM TblNdx AS t1
  WHERE (ticker = '^IXIC') 
  AND (date = (SELECT TOP (1) date
   FROM TblNdx AS t3
                        WHERE (ticker = '^IXIC')
  ORDER BY time DESC))
  ORDER BY time DESC

Comment: hmmm... example code that contains WHERE (1=1) AND ...  

makes me laff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is this?

Note: I did not test, expect typos

```
;WITH todaydate as
(
  SELECT max(date) as date, ticker
  FROM tblndx
  group by ticker
),  yesterdaydate as
(
  SELECT max(time) as time, ticker
  FROM tblndx
  group by ticker
  having  DATEDIFF(Day, date, getdate()) = 1
)
SELECT ticker
    , date
    , time
    , [open]
    , high
    , low
    , [close]
    , volume
    , change
    , yeserdaydate.time as [yeserday time]
from tblndx
inner join todaydate on tblndx.ticker = todaydate.ticker and tblndx.date = todaydate.date
left join yesterdaydate on tblndx.ticker = yeserdaydate.ticker
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     SELECT ticker
    , date
    , time
    , [open]
    , high
    , low
    , [close]
    , volume
    , change
    , (SELECT TOP (1) [close] FROM TblNdx AS t2
            WHERE (DATEDIFF(day, date, t1.date) = 2) 
                             AND (ticker = t1.ticker)
            ORDER BY time DESC) AS LastClose
    FROM TblNdx AS t1
    WHERE (ticker = '^IXIC')    
    AND (date = (SELECT TOP (1) date
        FROM TblNdx AS t3
                    WHERE (ticker = '^IXIC')
    ORDER BY time DESC))
    ORDER BY time DESC
```

I should have been clearer, I needed last closing date all prices (close) most recent top 1 date... and then the last previous dates close prices TOP 1 time only...

CS